# Implementing a reversing counter in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am new to VHDL and I am trying to implement a counter that counts up from 0 to its maximum value, then automatically starts counting down once it reached the max value. This is my entity and architecture:

```
entity Rev_Counter is   -- self-reverting counter
    generic (
    counter_steps: integer:=256;                -- number of steps of the counter
    counter_output_size: integer:=8     -- smallest nr of bits to represent the biggest value of the counter
    );
    port (
    clock: in std_logic;                -- input clock signal
    output: out std_logic_vector (counter_output_size-1 downto 0)
    );
end Rev_Counter;
```

```
architecture Arh_Rev_Counter of Rev_Counter is
   signal count_sig: std_logic_vector (counter_output_size-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal count_dir: std_logic := '0';      -- 0 = count up, 1 = count down  
begin

Count: process (clock)
begin

    if (clock'event and clock = '1') then
        if (count_sig = counter_steps-1) then   -- revert the counting direction
            count_dir <= '1';       -- reached highest value, count down 
            count_sig <= count_sig - 1;
        elsif (count_sig = 0) then  -- revert the counting direction
            count_dir <= '0';       -- reached lowest value, count up  
            count_sig <= count_sig + 1;
        end if;

        if (count_dir = '0') then   -- perform count up
            count_sig <= count_sig + 1;
        elsif (count_dir = '1') then    -- preform count down
            count_sig <= count_sig - 1;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
output <= count_sig;

end architecture;
```

My problem is: when simulating this code, my counter counts up to FF normally, then it starts acting strange. After counting up to FF, it goes straight to 00, then FF, then 00 and so on, without the numbers in between. I would appreciate some help figuring out why it acts this way.

I found an alternative way to do it. I edited the `Count` process to look like this. However, I don't exactly understand what was wrong in the first place, therefore I'd still appreciate some insight.

```
    Count: process (clock)
    begin

        if (clock'event and clock = '1') then  
            if (count_dir = '0') then   
                count_sig <= count_sig + 1;
                if (count_sig = counter_steps - 1) then
                    count_sig <= count_sig - 1;
                    count_dir <= '1';
                end if;
            elsif (count_dir = '1') then
                count_sig <= count_sig - 1;
                if (count_sig = 0) then
                    count_dir <= '0';
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Your answer should likely be added to your question which can be modified to ask why it works and the original didn't.

Comment: @user1155120 I edited my post and removed the answer

Comment: Every named object in the process that behaves other than desired are signals, meaning their behavior can show up in simulation waveforms for troubleshooting if you were to provide a [mcve] allowing the issue to be replicated by your readers. You're only missing the entity's context clause and a simple testbench providing clock. Alternatively you could provide a waveform showing all the signals and demonstrating the transition from counting up and then toggling between 00 and FF. The same for the working process would be useful as a reference.

Comment: The idea is to point at specific times in the waveform and specific signal values instead of doing wavy handed word pictures, providing an enlightening search resource for future readers encountering the same or a similar problem.

Comment: Here's the wavy handed word picture version. The process that works you'll see the value where the direction turns around valid for two clocks. The process that progresses to alternating 00's and FF's instead sets the count_sig value to the other boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing `count_dir` one tick too late at either end.

Since it is a registered value, the effects of changing it have a 1 clock period delay. As a result, on reaching 0xFF `count_sig` will increment one more time (0x00) before reversing the direction. It will then count 'down' to 0xFF, reversing the direction again, resulting in the value constantly flicking between 0x00 and 0xFF.

Altering your conditions to change direction to `count_sig = counter_steps - 2` and `count_sig = 1` respectively gives you the behaviour you want.